# What terms describe the various parts of someone's name?

Tags: names

People tend to have at least one personal name and one family name. Some people also have middle names and nicknames. What terms describe other kinds of names, e.g.:

- What term describes additional names, such as those added after the middle name?
- What term describes surnames which combine two family names, joined by a hyphen?
- Are there any additional kinds of names? What are they called?

Comment: In some cases and in some societal groups, the middle name is the _patronymic_, the personal name of the father.

Comment: give a example for better understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- What term describes additional names, such as those added after the middle name?

The name after the first and middle names is usually a *surname* or *family name*.

- What term describes surnames which combine two family names, joined by a hyphen?

These are often called *double-barrelled names* or *double-barrelled surnames*.

- Are there any additional kinds of names? What are they called?

In much of the west, people usually have at least a *first name* and a *surname*. Sometimes they will have one or more *middle names*.

(There are many cultural exceptions: Hungary has the family name first and the given name last, Portugal with one or two given names and two family names, Iceland is *patronymic* and sometimes *matronymic*: the child's surname comes from one of their parent's given name.)

Usually people will be referred to by friends and family by the first name, but occasionally people will go by one of their middle names. This name is used to distinguish them from other people in the same family or with the same surname.

A *surname* is also known as *family name*.

The *first name* is sometimes called a *forename* and sometimes called a *Christian name*, whether the person was christened or not. A middle name can also be called these (although *first name* is usually restricted to the very first one), and in the plural they can refer to the first and middle names together.

A *nickname* is a shortened version of a given name, or can be a fun or even cruel name to refer to someone more familiarly.

Others end in *-onym*. For example,  a *demonym* is a resident of a place (eg Mancunian), a fake name or *pen name* is a *pseudonym*.

The list goes on and onnic. You can start listing groups of names (eg different types of given names such as Hebrew names, Germanc names, Celtic names), or names of things.

Comment: Well deserved upvote for a fairly detailed answer.

Comment: +1 great answer, but was hoping for official names for other additions like in John Doe II, or John Doe PhD, John Doe CPA, Sir John Doe, John Doe Jr