# What is the number written at the end of some names?

Tags: single-word-requests, names

As far as I can tell there is [Title/Suffix] [First Name] [Last Name/Surname] [Number].

I am confused on two things really:

- What do you call the last part of someone's name like "III" for 'the third'?
- Why do they call Mr./Mrs./etc the *suffix* of a name when it is actually the first part of the name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What terms describe the various parts of someone's name?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71089/what-terms-describe-the-various-parts-of-someones-name)

Comment: @jwpat7 No, the question that you've linked to mentions neither the "title" part of a name, nor what to call the "number" part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have it backwards. II/JR.... are the [suffix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_%28name%29).  Mr, Mrs. are the [Title or prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title)

Answer (score 6):

The [answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_%28name%29) is in Wikipedia. They are called *suffixes*, and more specifically *generational suffixes*. These are Sr., Jr., II, III, IV, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, **monarchical ordinal** is the name for the [number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarchical_ordinal) placed after a king or a Pope's name. It is also called a **regnal number** as it is appended to a [regnal name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regnal_name). In other cases like numbers appended after family names, a **familial ordinal** should do, though it is not at all common and unlikely to be understood. Instead one could just call it the ordinal number in one's name.

Also, Mr. and Mrs. are [English honorifics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_honorific), which are titles prefixing a person's name. I am not sure why you think they are suffixes.

Comment: No.  The question wasn't specifically about the number after the name of a king, queen or pope.  A man who has the exact same name as his father and his grandfather might be called "John Doe III" (pronounced "John Doe the third"), without being a king or a pope.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Perhaps a familial ordinal? I can't find any special names used though.

Comment: And it is, I believe, an entirely American custom.

Comment: Actually, the words "familial ordinal" are generally used to indicate the birth order within the family (ie first-born, second-born and so on); not the number at the end of the name.  Sorry.