# What are the parts of a name?

Tags: names, surnames

For example, in Latin America the full name would be like:

Ana María Gómez Sánchez

In that case, "Gómez" is her dad's last name, and "Sánchez" is her mum's single last name.

Let's pretend Ana María's dad's name is Gabriel Gómez Pérez. And her mum's name is Jessica Sánchez Flores. That way, Ana María gets both of those first last names.

What I want to know is what's the name of every part of the name? 
What's the last name, the middle name, the surname, and if there's more, haha.

Sorry if it's confusing, and thank you in advance!

Comment: There isn’t a global English ontology for all make structures in all languages and cultures in the world, so far as I’m aware. More: I’d be surprised if there were. English terminology is usually guilt and applied to artifacts found in English-speaking cultures, and their neighbors, attenuating with “cultural distance”. Hence the easy availability of the words “first name”, “surname”, when you wrote this question. So, are you thinking only of Latin American name structures? Or can you somehow else reduce the scope?

Comment: I've got an answer coming─presuming you are talking in the context of English, though. (?)

Comment: It's just that if someone from England asks a Latina "What's your full name?" And it appears with two "last names" how do you explain it? What's the grammar name for the second last name?

Comment: What you call each part of a name isn't grammar.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question relates to vocabulary for cultural aspects of Hispanic countries for which equivalents do not exist in English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates largely to terminology associated with cultural aspects of Hispanic countries for which equivalents do not exist in English. (after @David)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, “terminology” is better.

Comment: @David On the contrary, they do, such as *patronymic surname.*

Comment: @Lordology — Well that is technically English, and would be understood by Hispanic scholars.

Comment: Yeah.  I don't think this should be closed due to the fact that there *are* equivalents

Comment: @Lordology Perhaps because it's a duplicate then? [What terms describe the various parts of someone's name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71089/what-terms-describe-the-various-parts-of-someones-name/71143#71143).

Comment: No─this request asks for English words for foreign surnames i.e. the one listed in the OP's question, for example, *matronymic surname*.  I only provided the English part for context, because if I started blabbering about patronymic surnames to the OP it wouldn't really make sense.

Comment: Your example doesn't quite match the description you gave. If her father's last name is Pérez and her mother's (maiden) last name is Florez, then her name should actually be Ana María Pérez Flores. But, instead of that, you seem to have named her with her father's *middle* name and her mother's *middle* name. (Or, in other wording, their *first last* names rather than their *second last* names.) In short, I think you're confusing terminology—or at least not being explicit in the third sentence in your question. Then again, the question may be how to phrase the third sentence given the names.

Comment: This might be useful: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: This is highly dependent on culture.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked, here are the most of the possible parts of a name in English from my (BrE) perspective: You can skip to the bit about other languages if you wish; P.S> you seem to be asking about English and other languages(?)

**First name (forename):**

Pretty self-explanatory; the first part of someone's name.  When you are informally addressing someone known, you will typically only use their first name.

> **John** Smith

**Last (family) name:**

Also straightforward, the last part of someone's name, in most cases taken from their father (their family name).  You will typically introduce someone with their first and last name in a formal situation.  The first and last names of a person are generally called their *full name*, though this sometimes includes their middle name(s)<sup>*[Lexico Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/full_name)*</sup>.  In your case, the "Sánchez" part would be in English referred to as a **maternal** or **matronymic surname**.  There's a lot more on this [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surname)

> John **Smith**

**Middle name(s):**

These are the names that go in-between the first and last names, and are usually taken from grandparents/ancestors etc. A person can have several middle names.

> John **Edward Lawrence** Smith

**Nickname or moniker:**
These informal titles are almost exclusively used in conversation between friends, and pretty much never formally.  They are styled in writing usually like this:

> John **"Johnny"** Smith

**Honorary and Professional Titles:**

You achieve these titles either through gaining a degree.  First of all, a **professional title is achieved through education** (like a P.h.D [Doctorate] or MA[Master of Arts]).  A knighthood or, in the UK, something like an Order of the British Empire (OBE) **is achieved through services to your country**.  A **hereditary** title is inherited usually through parents e.g. "Count" or "Duke". 
Note that if you are a doctor and are knighted, you would put the *Sir* at the beginning and the "Dr." would become "P.h.D" at the end:

> **Sir** John Smith, **P.h.D**

In the same way, *Count* or some such takes precedence over *Sir*.  [There is more on this that is not of significant relevance here at Debrett's (via WayBackMachine)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160528222528/http://www.debretts.com/forms-address/titles/knight)

There is loads more on complicated English naming customs than is appropriate here at [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_name)

#### In other languages,

Spanish, as in your case:

> a person's name consists of a given name (simple or composite)
>   followed by two family names (surnames). Historically, the first
>   surname was the father's first surname, and the second the mother's
>   first surname.

If you're very interested in the complications of the Spanish naming system, there's a very long and detailed description at Wikipedia, which listing here would be inappropriate: [Spanish naming customs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_naming_customs)

To keep it simple and comprehendible:

All names taken from the mother are **matronymic or maternal**
All names taken from the father are **patronymic or paternal**

So, in an English description

> Ana María is her **personal forename** (See my part about English above; this is how it links)
>   
> Gómez is her **paternal surname**(taking precedence over the maternal one
> Sánchez is her **maternal surname**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It did! Thank you

Comment: The forename is also called "given name" or "Christian name". And I think the extra middle names that Catholics give during Confirmation are called "saint's names".

Comment: @Barmar +1 Nice to know.

Comment: @Barmar I've decided not to edit because I couldn't verify the saint's name-middle name link.  See more: [Saint's name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint's_name)

Comment: Yeah, that might have been an assumption on my part. I'm not Christian.